# cell.detailTextLabel.text not working... why

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

Using the following code I am getting the text.label but not the detailTextLabel.text. The NSLog is displaying correctly.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [eventLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [eventFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  

NSLog(@"%@", [eventFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

I also tried...

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [eventFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

I have not had problems with this before. Any suggestions?

John

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Make sure you're using an appropriate `UITableViewCellStyle` with this (anything but `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` should thus work). The cell's style is specified when you initialize it.

Comment: That was it!!!! I was using but UITableViewCellStyleDefault. I think I used what was provided when I created the class without thinking about. Thanks so much.

John

Comment: user278859: if John has answered your question then do accept his answer. Whats the use if you dont accept even correct answers?

Comment: @jbrennan have you filed a bug to Apple?, in their docs they say the default one can support a detailed text label...

Answer (score 24):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Do remember to change to **UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle**

Answer (score 2):

If you choose style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` , your `detailTextLabel.text` will show

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
```

[UITableView Source](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/)