# Label not displaying in UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

```
-viewDidLoad {
    tbl.rowHeight = 150;
    ary = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"asdf",@"asd",nil];
    ary2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"google",@"yahoo",nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [ary count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [ary2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
         return cell;
}
```

The problem for me is detailtextlabel not displaying in table view. Are there any errors in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below link

[In UITableView, cell.detailTextLabel.text isn't working… why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834199/in-uitableview-cell-detailtextlabel-text-isnt-working-why)

Comment: This should be a vote to close as duplicate, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have to set cell styleSubtitle as subtitle
like below

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using an UITableViewCellStyle anything but not UITableViewCellStyleDefault should this work, please see this for more details:

[cell.detailTextLabel.text not working... why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349279/cell-detailtextlabel-text-not-working-why)

Answer (score 1):

Change the uitableviestyltDEfault to uitableviewStyleSubtitle

Answer (score 0):

Anything but `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` should work with a detailLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Add detailtextLabel on the cell's contentView.